# Install custom document class under (Windows) MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, installing, document-classes, windows

I'm trying to create my own document class based on memoir.
But right now I can't even seem to add it to the right spot.

I put it in the user install path detailed here: https://miktex.org/kb/texmf-roots (Note that the path for Windows is missing the `AppData` part. In the MiKTeX console it shows the correct path)
And then refreshed the file name database (as detailed here: https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console) but when trying to typeset it won't find the cls file. I keep getting the error: `! LaTeX Error: File connectingmedia.cls' not found.`, but I have the file `connectingmedia.cls` in `%AppData%\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\connectingmedia`, as it should be. The path `%AppData%\MiKTeX\2.9` is configured as a TEXMF root dir in MiKTeX. (The default)

Comment: Did you try to create a system-wide `TeXMF-local` root, with the TDS architecture?

Comment: The path `%AppData%\MiKTeX\2.9` is configured like that by default already.

Comment: Personally I have both. Perhaps both roots are not supposed to contain the same kind of things?

Comment: I mean I also have the system wide root. Though I’d rather keep my files out of there.

Comment: Did you refresh the file name database in both User and Admin mode? (In case you have a multi-user installation.)

Comment: @moewe incredible. That seems to have done the trick. First user mode refresh, then admin refresh... That actually did the trick.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments

Comment: Would this be worth a bug report?